# Create a user defined function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create an user defined function with take 2 parameters the federal filing status char 1 where have data like S and M which are single and married and the second parameter is state char 2 where have data created already in a table EmployeeTransfers have MS,FL,NY etc..

I have create a functoin that returns one of the code which is of data type char 1
with this logic example:
IF State = NY and
Federal Filing Single(S) then  Code is A
or Federal Filing Married(M) then Code is B

etc...

so there my code my returns are NULL i dnt knw how to set the return more specific

```
create function dbo.GetStateFilingStatus
(
    @federalfilingstatus char(1),
    @state char(2)
) returns char(1)
as
begin
    declare @code char(1) = null

    select @federalfilingstatus = EmpFederalFilingStatus from EmployeeTransfers
    where @state  = EmpTransferState

    if (@state = 'MS' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S')
    set @code = 'A'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'MS' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'M')
    set @code = 'M'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'NJ' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S')
    set @code = 'B'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'NJ' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'M')
    set @code = 'A'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'AZ' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S')
    set @code = 'A'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'AZ' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'M')
    set @code = 'B'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'CT' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S')
    set @code = 'F'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'CT' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'M')
    set @code = 'M'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'DC' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S')
    set @code = 'S'
    return @code 

    if (@state = 'DC' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'M')
    set @code = 'Y'
    return @code 

end
Go
```

I tried to execute it with

```
select dbo.GetStateFilingStatus(EmpTransferState ,EmpFederalFilingStatus) as StateFilingStatus from EmployeeTransfers
```

my returns are nulls.

Comment: Any reason you have tagged MySQL*and* SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is returning at the very first return because it doesn't know it's part of the if block. Just remove all the returns and have one return at the very end.

A better way of doing this is to create a lookup table that you can join to. That way, if you ever need to add a filing status or state, you can just add a row. And if you need to modify a code, you can just update the table.

Comment: I agree. Don't use a UDF (unless this is another dopey homework question). Use a table

Comment: Thank for the lesson ,also i noticed other problem that was the order of parameter so i fixed write state first and then federalfilingstatus because the if was reverse order i wrote first state and federalfilistatus which the parameter were reverse

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `BEGIN` and `END` statements after the `IF`, otherwise SQL will execute treat the first statement as being inside the IF block and the rest after. Anyway, you don't need to use the `@code` variable here at all, just return the value directly:

```
if (@state = 'MS' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S')
    return 'A' 

if (@state = 'MS' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'M')
    return 'M' 

if (@state = 'NJ' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S')
    return 'B' 

--etc...
```

A better solution however would be to use a lookup table instead of this complicated list of conditionals. That way you can add to it and not have to worry about maintaining a complex stored procedure.

Comment: Thank for the lesson ,also i noticed other problem that was the order of parameter so i fixed write state first and then federalfilingstatus because the if was reverse order i wrote first state and federalfilistatus which the parameter were reverse

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `BEGIN` and `END` in your `IF` statements:

```
if (@state = 'MS' AND @federalfilingstatus = 'S') begin
    set @code = 'A'
    return @code 
end
```

What happened before is that, without the `BEGIN - END` statements the `RETURN` statement is executed after evaluating the first `IF` statement.

---

Alternatively, you can use `IF` - `ELSE IF` combination to set the value of `@code` and put the `RETURN` statement at the end.

```
IF <condition> BEGIN
    SET @code = 'A'
ELSE IF <condition> BEGIN
    SET @code = 'B'    
END

RETURN @code
```

Comment: Thank for the lesson ,also i noticed other problem that was the order of parameter so i fixed write state first and then federalfilingstatus because the if was reverse order i wrote first state and federalfilistatus which the parameter were reverse.